# Drop down box which shows lowest price of products in sql database

Tags: php

Hi guys basically I am totally new to php and I need to have a drop down list which will show the lowest price of whiskeys within my database in a numerical order. I have made several attemps but I haven't been successful. Help would be much appreicated. Here is what I have done so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
require('config.php'); 
<body>

<select>enter code here
  <option value="Lowest Price">Lowest Price</option>
  <option value="Highest Price">Highest Price</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>

?>
```

Comment: do you have any sql to share?

Comment: Yup, with a query for your Whiskeys!! Let's do Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Need your query and how your are performing that query, but with PDO could be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `price` ASC";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
echo "<select>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=\"$row[price]\">\"$row[whiskey]\"</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to select the lowest price from the Average_price column in the Whiskeys table

Answer (score 0):

Basically is something like this;

```
$query = 'select id, name from table order by price ASC'
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
<select>enter code here
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Considering you are using `mysqli` (i hope you do), and procedural PHP.